# Spring inject an object created using an instance called from a static method

Tags: java, spring, factory, code-injection

I have an object created as follows:

```
 serviceValidatorObject = ServiceFactory.getInstance().getServiceValidator()
```

The object is created from a call to static method, `getInstance()`, then an instance method, `getServiceValidator()`.

I want to use Spring injection to configure this instead.

The trouble is the ServiceFactory is legacy code that I cannot change.

I know Spring supports injection through a factory class static or instance method, but is there anyway I can configure the object creation above in Spring?

Answer (score 4):

```
<bean id="exampleBean"
      factory-bean="myFactoryBean"
      factory-method="createInstance"/>
```

In your case, exampleBean is your `serviceValidatorObject`, factory-bean is `serviceFactory`, and the factory-method is `getServiceValidator`.  You might need this, too:

```
<bean id="serviceFactory"
      factory-method="getInstance"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this bean definition:

```
<bean id="serviceValidatorObject" factory-bean="serviceFactory" factory-method="getServiceValidator"/>  
<bean id="serviceFactory" class="<package>.ServiceFactory" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this using:

```
<bean id="myCreatedObjectBean" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetClass">
        <value>com.mycompany.MyFactoryClass</value>
    </property>
    <property name="targetMethod">
        <value>myFactoryMethod</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Then you can use either @Resource or @Autowired + @Qualifier to inject into your object directly.

For this example, your applicationContext.xml should contain:

```
<!-- this allows Spring to create an instance of your Factory -->
<bean id="serviceFactoryBean" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetClass">
        <value>yourpackage.ServiceFactory</value>
    </property>
    <property name="targetMethod">
        <value>getInstance</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- this allows Spring to use the factory instance to create the instance of ServiceValidator -->
<bean id="serviceValidatorBean" factory-bean="serviceFactoryBean" factory-method="getServiceValidator"/>
```

And then you could inject into your code via:

```
@Resource(name = "serviceValidatorBean")
ServiceValidator serviceValidator;
```